# is solana program (smart contract) immutable?

Tags: program, deploy, redeploy

I confuse a bit about this. If I can deploy a program as many as I want to a specific account so program in Solana is mutable. It's unlike other blockchains like Ethereum when deployed contract its contract are immutable along with its address

Answer (score 4):

**Redeploy a program**

A program can be redeployed to the same address to facilitate rapid development, bug fixes, or upgrades. Matching keypair files are generated once so that redeployments will be to the same program address.

```
solana program deploy <PROGRAM_FILEPATH>
```

**Immutable programs**

A program can be marked immutable, which prevents all further redeployments, by specifying the --final flag during deployment:

```
solana program deploy <PROGRAM_FILEPATH> --final
```

Comment: I found your Git repository very useful. Can You please tell Me How to sign multiple transactions with only one signature popup?
I have to send multiple transactions from my front end, usually, for every transaction, the user is asked to sign on Wallet. Is there a way to sign all of them at once in User Wallet, instead of the popup happening for all of the transactions?

Comment: It has already been asked https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-is-the-best-practice-to-sign-and-send-multiple-transaction-at-once-in-solan