# What is the best practice to sign and send multiple transaction at once in solana with one popup of phantom wallet?

Tags: transactions, web3.js, phantom, send-transaction, sign

What is the best practice to handle multiple transaction to sign and send at once with one popup of phantom wallet ?

Answer (score 3):

In Solana, a `Transaction` can contain multiple `instructions`.

Here is an example of signing 2 `instructions`, 1 for adding compute budget, and another calling an Anchor program in same transaction.

```
import {
    Connection,
    PublicKey,
    SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
    Transaction,
    ComputeBudgetProgram,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from '@solana/web3.js'
import { useAnchorWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react'

...

const wallet = useAnchorWallet()

...

// create Transaction
const transaction = new Transaction();

// create add compute budget Instruction
const additionalComputeBudgetInstruction =
    ComputeBudgetProgram.requestUnits({
        units: 1400000,
        additionalFee: 0,
});

// create anchor instruction
const tx = program.instruction.initialize(
    {
        accounts:  {
             payer: wallet.publicKey,
             clock: SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
             systemProgram,
        },
    }
)

// add instructions to transaction
transaction.add(additionalComputeBudgetInstruction)
transaction.add(tx)

// sign transaction            
const signature = wallet.signTransaction(transaction)
console.log('Your transaction signature', signature)
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to sign with the Transaction instance instead of TransactionInstruction instance

Comment: No problem, If I answered your question, please mark this as answered and upvote it . Thank you :)) https://solana.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: Sure, also please let me know, do I need to execute sendRawTransaction on each signed transaction or it can be possible at once ?

Comment: you have to sign for each yeah, you can create a function that takes a list of transactions and then loops through all of them and run `sendRawTransaction` But there's no implicit implementation in Solana.