# Multiple instructions in one transactions using Anchor TS client (@project-serum/anchor)

Tags: anchor, instructions

I would like to add multiple instructions into a single transaction, using Anchor TS (@project-serum/anchor). Here is an example how this works with Solana Web3.js (@solana/web3.js): [What is the best practice to sign and send multiple transaction at once in solana with one popup of phantom wallet?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2248/what-is-the-best-practice-to-sign-and-send-multiple-transaction-at-once-in-solan/2259#2259).

Is there a way to do this using Anchor TS (@project-serum/anchor) as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep! Assuming you have something like this:

```
await program.methods
  .createPixel(x, y, 0, 0, 255)
  .accounts({
    pixel: pixelKeypair.publicKey,
    user: anchorProvider.wallet.publicKey,
    systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
  })
  .signers([pixelKeypair])
  .rpc()
```

You can use either `.preInstructions([])` or `.postInstructions([])` to add instructions before or after the Anchor instruction.

Here's an example:

```
await program.methods
  .createPixel(x, y, 0, 0, 255)
  .accounts({
    pixel: pixelKeypair.publicKey,
    user: anchorProvider.wallet.publicKey,
    systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
  })
  .signers([pixelKeypair])
  .postInstructions([
    // add an instruction to the transaction to send 1 lamport 
    web3.SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: anchorProvider.wallet.publicKey,
      toPubkey: anchorProvider.wallet.publicKey,
      lamports: 1,
    })
  ])
  .rpc()
```

Comment: This is a nice answer, but if you want to arrange your instructions in the same way as each other using `tx.add(instruction)`, rather than arrange your other instructions around Anchor instruction, the other answer is better.

Answer (score 4):

You may prefer to turn your Anchor instruction into a regular web3.js instruction, using Anchor's `.instruction()` to **get the instruction as a normal `Instruction` you can use with `web3.js`**

You can then use web3.js `tranaction.add()` to add the Anchor instruction to your transaction, then use the normal web3.js `connection.sendTransaction()` to process your transaction.

For example:

```
let tx = new Transaction();

// Add a compute unit limit instruction (a normal instruction)
const setComputeUnitLimitInstruction = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit(
  { units: 200_000 }
);
tx.add(setComputeUnitLimitInstruction);

// Add the 'reveal' instruction from my Anchor program
const revealInstruction = await program.methods
  .reveal(id, encodedData)
  .instruction();
tx.add(revealInstruction);

const transactionSignature = await connection.sendTransaction(tx, [sender], {
  skipPreflight: true,
});
```

Comment: Good point! You can also do `.transaction()` and then add instructions if that's easier. It's a really nicely thought out API :)

Comment: Oh sweet, didn't know that. Great API.

Comment: I really liked this answer - being able to add my transactions using normal web3.js methods was very convenient - so I added to the example a little. I hope that's OK.